# Adding vertices on mouse click in DirectX 12

Tags: c++, vertex-buffer, directx-12

I'm trying to implement a functionality where a vertex is added whenever the user clicks
on the viewport.

So far I've managed to draw vertices with the mouse using `D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINESTRIP`,
but the working implementation simply creates a new vertex buffer every click^^

That's how I came to my new implementation after hours of research and trial & error because I totally
don't get how a `D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD` works combined with a `D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT`

I've noticed a strange behavior: Whenever I reach 10 clicks (the defined number of `DYNAMIC_VERTEX_BUFFER_MAX_VERTICES`), the linestrip is drawn. Before I don't reach the vertex buffer size, nothing is drawn.

In addition I ran PIX debugger to see the contents of my vertex buffer. The vertices are initially stored in the buffer with (0, 0, 0, 0) and when I reach the limit (10 clicks), they magically appear with their correct values.

Here are 2 screenshots in comparison

[Vertices NOT empty after 10 clicks][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oah1Y.png

[Vertices empty( < 10 clicks][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWJgz.png

Here is the implementation I came along with -> the call order is `CreateDefaultBuffer` once and then
every time a vertex is added I call `UpdateUploadHeap` and then `BindVertexBufferView`

````
void CreateDefaultBuffer(ID3D12Device& device, ComPtr<ID3D12GraphicsCommandList> commandList, const void* rawData, const UINT bufferSize)
    {
        // create default vertex buffer
        const CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES heapProp(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT);
        const auto buf = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(BufferSize * DYNAMIC_VERTEX_BUFFER_MAX_VERTICES); //DYNAMIC_VERTEX_BUFFER_MAX_VERTICES is 10
        auto hr = device.CreateCommittedResource(
            &heapProp,
            D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
            &buf,
            D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST,
            nullptr,
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&D3DBuffer));
        VALIDATE((hr == ERROR_SUCCESS), "CreateCommittedResource failed");

        D3DBuffer->SetName(L"Dynamic Vertex Buffer"); // set name for debugger

        const auto transition = 
            CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(D3DBuffer.Get(), D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST,
                                                 D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_VERTEX_AND_CONSTANT_BUFFER);
        commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &transition);

        
    }

    void UpdateUploaeHeap(ID3D12Device& device, ComPtr<ID3D12GraphicsCommandList> commandList, const void* rawData, const UINT bufferSize)
    {
        // create upload buffer to copy vertices into default buffer
        const CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES heapPropUpload(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD);
        const auto bufUpload = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(bufferSize);
        const auto hr = device.CreateCommittedResource(
            &heapPropUpload,
            D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
            &bufUpload,
            D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ,
            nullptr,
            IID_PPV_ARGS(D3DBufferUpload.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));
        VALIDATE((hr == ERROR_SUCCESS), "CreateCommittedResource failed");

        D3DBufferUpload->SetName(L"Upload Buffer for copying into Dynamic Vertex Buffer"); // set name for debugger

        D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexData = {};
        vertexData.pData = rawData;
        vertexData.RowPitch = bufferSize;
        vertexData.SlicePitch = vertexData.RowPitch;

        UpdateSubresources(commandList.Get(), D3DBuffer.Get(), D3DBufferUpload.Get(), 0, 0, 1, &vertexData);
    }

    D3D12_VERTEX_BUFFER_VIEW vertexBufferView;

    void BindVertexBufferView()
    {
        vertexBufferView.BufferLocation = D3DBuffer->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
        vertexBufferView.StrideInBytes = sizeof(meshData.vertices[0]);
        vertexBufferView.SizeInBytes = static_cast<UINT>(meshData.vertices.size()) * vertexBufferView.StrideInBytes;
    }```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resources allocated from the `D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT` heap are placed in memory where the GPU can access them. There's *no* guarantee that the CPU can access it at all. In some architectures, there's no difference and all memory can be accessed by both at all times (Unified Memory Architecture such as the Xbox).  In other architectures, default memory is dedicated video RAM that is not accessible from the CPU at all.

In order to place data *into* `D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT` from CPU system memory, you need to copy the data into a resource allocated from the `D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD` heap. This memory is explicitly designated to be visible to *both* the CPU and GPU. This can be the "PCIe aperture" or some other mechanism.

You can render *directly* from `D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD` memory for VBs/IBs and textures. This is equivalent to the DirectX 11 concept of `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC`. That said, there's usually a performance penalty to rendering directly from this type of memory.

You also use `D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD` heap memory directly for Constant Buffers (CB) as these are modified a lot during render.

A key thing to remember is that DirectX 12 does *not* do "buffer renaming" for you. If you change a resource while it's being used by the GPU, it's going to cause problems with the render. The application is responsible for ensuring the  resource is *no longer being used for drawing* before you change it.

For example, after you have called the `UpdateSubresources` helper *nothing* is actually on the video card yet. You have to **Close** the associated command-list and **Execute** it. Then sometime *later* the copy is actually performed by the GPU (or DMA engine). The resource barriers take care of the dependencies between resources in the same command-list, but *you* still have to make sure you don't change the resource data from the CPU until it's actually done.

The practical up-shot of this fact is that if you are setting a resource in the `UPLOAD` heap, then using it in a command-list, you *must leave it alone and alive* until the task you scheduled is actually completed on the GPU. If you want to render with a different version of the same resource, you need to create a new instance of it for the next draw or next frame. You have to wait 2 or 3 frames worth of rendering to know that the original resource you used is actually done.

There are a number of ways to handle the recycling the memory and tracking its usage lifetime, but it looks like you have just a single resource which isn't going to work unless you stall out the GPU *every* frame. For a 'dynamic' VB/IB, you going to need 2 or 3 copies of it so you can swap between them each frame.

> See [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki) and in particular the `ResourceUploadBatch` and `GraphicsMemory` classes.

Comment: I have managed to implement it in my code exactly how it is documented here: 

**[GraphicsMemory](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/GraphicsMemory)**

I have also called the `vbUpload.Reset()` and did explicitly call `graphicsMemory->GarbageCollect()` at the end of my render loop(after the GPU has finished working on that cycle)

It turns out, that I still get a huge memory leak. After drawing approximately 3000 vertices, my memory usage went up to from 300MB to 1,2 GB. Any suggestions for what I could have missed here?

Comment: Problem solved. Human error on my side, as I had forgotten to call `graphicsMemory->Commit(commandQueue.Get())`. It works as intended now